# How to call an external javascript library function within a Typescript class using Angular 2/4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Typescript class `class.component.ts` in which I want to call methods which are defined within my Javascript class. This Javascript class is headed within: `/assets/js/*initlibrary.js*`. This javascript library is automatically called when the project is initialized.

My question is: how can I reach out to this javascript library and call the function in it? Is it required to import it in a way like `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';`? If so, how should I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want to import anything first you have to be sure you're exporting stuff (a class, a function, whatever) from your javascript file.

Comment: in my javascript library methods are just defined like `function method() {}` should I make them more exportable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an external library inside your angular project, there are many requirements.

**1. Declare your javascript library inside your angular-cli.json** :

```
"scripts": [
    "../assets/js/yourlibrary.js"
]
```

With this instruction, you can use your library function inside your typescript code, but it will not be able to compile (transpile).

**2. Create a definition of your library**

A typescript definition has an extension file ends with ***.d.ts***. You can create it inside your project and reference it from your tsconfig.json.

Here is an example of the EXIF library definition that I've created :

```
/// EXIF.d.ts

declare module EXIF {
    interface EXIFStatic {
       getData(img, callback): boolean;
       getTag(img, tag): any;
       getAllTags(img): any;
       pretty(img): any;
       readFromBinaryFile(file): any;
    }
}

declare var EXIF: EXIF.EXIFStatic;

declare module "EXIF" {
     export = EXIF;
}
```

In my code, I use like this :

EXIF.getData(img,callback);

You can find more example here : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types

**3. Reference the definition of your library**

Here is an example of my tsconfig.json file :

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./typings" // I have create a typings folder inside my src project folder
],
"types": [
   "EXIF" // Reference of your EXIF.d.ts inside your typings folder
]
```

The definition allows you to get autocomplete function name when you code (if you use Visual studio code), and allows angular to build your project.

Comment: Thank you @Nicolas. Thats not so easy as I thought. At step 2, should I declare my js library exactly the same as you do, with all the methods that are in the library?

Comment: It depends of your library. If you want to reference a JQuery plugin, you have to add new functions to JQuery interface. If you have developed functions, just declare a class and add the definition of each methods.